# Assign NA to columns based on their name and another column value

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to assign NAs to columns based on their name and another column value.
Like in the following example:

Given dataframe iris, I would like to assign NA to all columns whose name starts with "Sepal" and column "Species" == "setosa"

A solution using dplyr mutate_at/mutate_if is preferable, any other solution is also welcome.

I tried

```
iris %>%
   mutate_if(str_detect(names(.), pattern = "Sepal") & (.$Species == "setosa") , function(x){x <- NA})

Error in tbl_if_vars(.tbl, .p, .env, ..., .include_group_vars = .include_group_vars) : 
  length(.p) == length(tibble_vars) is not TRUE
```

Comment: `myIris <- iris; myIris[myIris$Species=="setosa", grepl("^Sepal", colnames(myIris))] <- NA`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `dplyr`, select vars that contain "Sepal" and assign NA to those rows where Species is "setosa":

```
iris %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("Sepal")), funs(ifelse(Species == "setosa", NA, .)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or even shorter:

```
iris %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("Sepal")), 
            funs(na_if(Species, "setosa")))
```